# Google Analytics Destination Goal not Being Tracked

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a Google Analytics Goal using the following settings(this is a simplified version of what's being used):

Goal setup: custom,
Goal type: destination,
Destination: "Equals to" /en-us/industries/chemical-petrochemical ,
Value=Off,
Funnel=Off

Here's the Google Tag Manager Javascript I use on the page:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TSLS6W');</script>
```

When I hit the /en-us/industries/chemical-petrochemical page on the site, I see the page being hit under Content in the Real-time reporting section of Google Analytics, so I know it is seeing the page.  However, I never see anything registered in the Conversions section of the Real-time reporting.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have a filter that could be altering the page path perhaps? Can you post a screenshot of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a filter was preventing the goal from being reached.  The filter was pre-appending the hostname of the URL.

Comment: Good catch! That's one of the things I had in mind. ;)